# Alternative meanings of "there it is"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Can the expression "there it is" be used with the meaning of "Oh, now I understand what you were talking about!" or "Oh, now I see what the problem was"?

Also, what are the alternative meanings of "there it is"? (Beside an exclamation that I have found something I was looking for).

Comment: All these meanings amount to "I have just pinpointed *it*."

Comment: Can you provide a sample sentence or two that exemplifies the first meaning you're asking about?

Comment: "Now I get it" seems more natural.

Comment: In the slang world there are a few [other meanings](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=there+it+is) and another when prepended with [Whoomp!](https://genius.com/Tag-team-whoomp-there-it-is-lyrics).  It could also be an awkward way to say "there you have it".

Comment: "THERE it is!", "There IT is", "There it IS". emphasis.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When saying "there it is," a person usually means that something being sought for has at last been found, as the question notes.  Most often, that something is a concrete, tangible object:

> Alice: I can't find my cellphone.  Have you seen it?
>
> Bob: Have you checked in the refrigerator?
>
> Alice: (opening fridge door) Why would it be in .... Ah, *there it is*.

Or

> Dave: Fred's directions said we need to turn left on Maple Avenue to get to the party.  Do you see any Maple Avenue?
>
> Charlene: (pointing to a distant street sign) Yes, *there it is.*
>
> Dave: Wow, good eyesight.

However, the sought after subject can also be a more abstract or figurative thing, such as comprehension.  The question also mentions this.

> Louis: I don't get it.  What happened to the baker?
>
> Carrol: Well, you see, the Snark was a Boojum after all.
>
> Louis: Oh.  *There it is.*

In this case, the response is often given in a drawn-out, almost sing-song voice: *Oooooooh, therrrrre iit iiiiis.*

One additional meaning expresses that a speaker or writer has just laid out a detailed explanation, and is providing a summary.

> Professor: So *there it is,* class.  The cycle of cellular division involves interphase, prophase, prometaphase, metaphase, anaphase, and telophase.
>
> Students: (half applaud, the other half are startled awake.)

Finally, a meaning given by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/there-it-is) and [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/there_it_is) says that "this is the state of affairs, this is the situation."  In other words, whether one likes it or not, and there is nothing one can do to change it.

> But *there it is*: you can't wait now till spring; and you can't go till the reports come back.     (J.R.R. Tolkien THE LORD OF THE RINGS)

Comment: If my "seeking for comprehension" example is too esoteric for anyone, please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunting_of_the_Snark.

Comment: Thank you for such a great and thorough answer! I wonder, are there any other expressions that someone can use to indicate that he finally got the situation? Not just "Oh, I got it!", but rather something cool, neat and hilarious.

Comment: Not hilarious, but there's **Eureka**.

Comment: @ezpresso - That sounds like to roots of a new question to ask here.

Answer (score 5):

I think you *could* use the phrase "there is is" with the meaning you suggest, but it doesn't seem particularly natural and I can't recall cases of the phrase being used that way. Here are a couple of alternative meanings:

**The Truth is Revealed!**

One meaning, in my experience when the phrase is "***and* there it is**", is something like:

"*Events have unfolded to reveal their true nature*".

So for example when someone is pretending to be nice but can't keep up the facade, when they break back into their usual character an onlooker might say "***and* there it is**".

This doesn't just apply to people, it could be applied to a whole series of events, the meaning of which mightn't be clear until later. With this meaning, it was a common phrase in the TV Series *Scrubs* (which I'm currently re-watching).

**I've Done It!**

In the same way a person might say "there it is" when they *find* something, you can can also use this phrase when you *produce* something. So if you're baking a cake, once it's ready one might present it saying "there it is". Used this way, it's almost equivalent to the old "Q.E.D." or "Q.E.F." in mathematics.

Comment: _"I think you could use the phrase 'there is is' with the meaning you suggest, but it doesn't seem particularly natural and I can't recall cases of the phrase being used that way."_ It's used in "arty" contexts quite a bit, e.g. frequently in _The West Wing_ dialog.

Answer (score 3):

In an argument "there it is" can be an exclamation of disgust at a stock argument the opponent brings up all the time. Used often in sitcoms to highlight a response by a spouse that they bring up in every argument.

Comment: I agree with this. I think it is closely related to my answer as it involves people "reverting to type" and "revealing their true nature".

Answer (score 2):

I'm a programmer and I say this frequently (usually to myself) when I finally find a solution to a problem I've been working on for some time. "Ah, there it is!"

So yes, I think it can be used in this way.

Comment: That's not _quite_ the same thing.

Comment: An utterance of autolalia can be complete gibberish to everyone else, yet make perfect sense to the speaker.  It is not governed by rules that generalize to the language as such.

Answer (score 1):

"I get it" or "I get it now"
Sounds much more natural to me because get takes the place of understand
"I get that concept now" vs. "I understand that concept now"

Answer (score 1):

An alternative idiomatic expression with the meaning you intended is: "*Now I **see the light***!"

TFD(idioms):

> **[see the light](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/see+the+light)**
>   *Fig*. to understand something clearly at last.
>   After a lot of studying and asking many questions, I finally saw the light.
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by
>   The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.

Answer (score 0):

"There it is" can be used if something missing has been located, or something whose arrival or occurrence has been awaited or anticipated has arrived or occurred.

There has to be a context for understanding what "it" refers to.

So, no, "there it is" cannot, out of the blue, carry the interpretation "now I see what the problem was".

It can only work if the preceding conversation establishes an antecedent for "it" which is sought after and finally found, or expected to happen and finally happens.

> A: "I still don't have the whole picture; some key information is missing which is preventing me from seeing what the problem was."
>
> B: [ ... gives explanation ... ]
>
> A: "Ah, and there it is."

Here, *it* refers to the sought-after key information, which now allows A to see what the problem was. A acknowledges that B has provided it.

Comment: _"So, no, 'there it is' cannot, out of the blue, carry the interpretation "now I see what the problem was"."_ Sure it can. -1

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I'm not convinced by your line of argumentation.  Out of the blue, it isn't even grammatical; prior context is needed for the pronoun "it' to have an antecedent.

Comment: I don't have time to convince you; I'm just here to anecdotally let you know that this form is accepted and used (e.g. _The West Wing_). You're over-thinking the grammatical prerequisites; real language doesn't always work that way. Your analysis is dubious anyway; in the weather report "it's sunny", the meaning of "it" is implied with no prior context required.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition "It" has an understood antecedent in "it is raining" and "it is getting late", etc. The prior context for that is the language rule for understood subjects.  I don't watch television, but maybe this series is on a torrent somewhere? Can you cite the season and episode number of *The West Wing* where this usage occurs? If possible, the approximate time or other means of identifying where in the episode it is spoken. Thanks.

Comment: One particular example that immediately comes to mind is Season 2 Episode 11 "The Leadership Breakfast" at 32:23. Beyond that you'll have to do your own research on this usage, but again I assure you it's perfectly reasonable. Just because _you_ aren't familiar with it doesn't mean it isn't widely understood otherwise.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I'm looking at the transcript here; http://www.westwingtranscripts.com/search.php?flag=getTranscript&id=33   It doesn't corroborate your claims even remotely.  "There it is" is spoken twice. Both with established context, and not meaning "I see what the problem was".  First one is spoken by Toby. The character previously said "missed one"; it refers to that. Second instance is spoken by Sam. The characters are brainstorming about what to say to the press. It seems to express Sam's opinion that words which were just said are the sound bite he is looking for. Others agree.

Comment: Perhaps you'd get a better idea of what's going on if you actually watched the episode as, like much in life, many cues come from inflections, gestures and other body language. The problem in that scene was how to spin a story to the press; the "it" that was found was the solution to that problem. "There it is" as in "you've got it". It's very clear if you actually watch the episode, as I have done some 15 or 16 times. Either way, I have little interest in continuing to defend the point - I've made it, and I stand by it. You are, of course, free to continue to disagree! Have a good weekend

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Your idea contains a logical flaw: I have already confirmed copious context in the transcript to properly understand the usage. It is not "out of the blue" and the meaning refers to something expected or sought after appearing (consistent with my answer). Watching the episode is not going to **shrink** the amount of context uncovered to invalidate that reasoning; if anything, it iwll only reveal more.  15, 16 times? No wonder you have no time ...

Comment: Regardless, I'm afraid that your interpretation is miles wide of the mark, and that would be clear to anyone who knows the characters or actually _watches_ the episode in question. And your little personal dig there was not really called for, was it? What, you have no hobbies? Charming fellow.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Doesn't the conversation between A and B in my answer demonstrate the same thing: that with (even just a little) context, the phrase *can* have the meaning in question? If we have to know the characters of the TV series to get the right interpretation, doesn't that just add up to even more context, making it it even less "out of the blue"?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition In your earlier explanation of the scene, you somehow didn't notice that my comment made exactly the same explanation. I said, *'The characters are brainstorming about what to say to the press. ["there it is"] seems to express Sam's opinion that words which were just said are the sound bite he is looking for.'* You said '*The problem in that scene was how to spin a story to the press; the "it" that was found was the solution to that problem. "There it is" as in "you've got it"*'.  But that is exactly the same interpretation. Hello? Miles wide of the mark, what?